# Http requests with OkHttp Interceptor doesn't works

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit with OkHttp Interceptor to work with API.
Interceptor adding cookie header to each request.
Interceptors code:

```
class AddCookiesInterceptor: Interceptor {

    @Inject
    lateinit var cookiesDao: CookiesDao

    init {
        App.getAppComponent().inject(this)
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        cookiesDao.getAll()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { cookies ->
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", "JWT=" + cookies.jwt)
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
}
```

While debuging i see, that interceptor updates request and adds cookie header with value, but when server reachs the request it returns an error (400 http code auth again).
if i manualy add Header into request like this

```
    @GET("/api.tree/get_element/")
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json", "X-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest", "Cookie: jwt_value")
    fun getElementId(): Maybe<ResponseBody>
```

Api returns 200 http code and it works.

Comment: What happens if you omit `"JWT=" +`?

Comment: @Jameido requests requires authtorization. Without token (JWT) server returns "400 - Bad Request" and message "Authorize again"

Comment: What i meant is doing this `builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookies.jwt)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are adding the header asynchronously, this is a "timeline" of what's happening in your flow:

init builder -> ask for cookies -> proceed with chain -> receive cookies dao callback -> add header to builder which has been already used

What you need to do is retrieve the cookies synchronously, to accomplish this you can use the [BlockingObseervable](https://rxjava-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Blocking-Observable-Operators/) and get something like this.
Using a synchronous function won't cause any trouble since the interceptor is already running on a background thread.

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
    val cookies = cookiesDao.getAll().toBlocking().first()
    builder.addHeader("Cookie", "JWT=" + cookies.jwt)
   
    return chain.proceed(builder.build())
}
```

Comment: Thank you fro the answer. I think BlockingObservable was added in RxJava 3, i don't have these classes and methods in my RxJava2 lib. I tried ```cookiesDao.getAll().blockingFirst()```
but it isn't works